# jQuery object cast to string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can help me please with a jquery object problem.

The problem is the following, I have this code:

```
url = '<a href="http://url.com">Name</a>';
otherValue = "Other Value";

x = jQuery(url).text(otherValue);
console.log(x);         
console.log(typeof(x));
```

This return :

```
[<a href=​"http:​/​/url.com">​Other Value​</a>​]
object
```

How I make for cast this object and finally get a string?

Thank's

Comment: Are you trying to get the String representation of `<a href...` ?

Comment: Yes!! I want get the string representation!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `console.log(x[0].outerHTML);`

Explain: `x[0]` gives you the `HTMLAnchorElement` object, `HTMLAnchorElement.outerHTML` gives you the html string.

Comment: Now I have this problem: may be than outerHTML replace me ">" "<" characters ??

<a href="http://url.com/place/mr-mofongo/">&lt;span class="ac_match"&gt;Name&lt;/span&gt;</a>

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link.

```
url = '<a href="http://url.com">Name</a>';
otherValue = "Other Value";

x = jQuery(url).text(otherValue);
alert(x[0].outerHTML);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SRjfq/